# Failing to install SOAP::Lite

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

I am having problem to install SOAP::Lite

I am using perl, v5.8.8 on CentOS 5.9

I am getting an error:

```
Failed Test                 Stat Wstat Total Fail  Failed  List of Failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t    2   512     2    2 100.00%  1-2
6 tests and 25 subtests skipped.
Failed 1/33 test scripts, 96.97% okay. 2/854 subtests failed, 99.77% okay.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

How to fix so it can install SOAP::Lite?

Full Output:

```
cp lib/SOAP/Lite.pm blib/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm
cp lib/SOAP/Fault.pod blib/lib/SOAP/Fault.pod
cp bin/SOAPsh.pl blib/script/SOAPsh.pl
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/SOAPsh.pl
cp bin/stubmaker.pl blib/script/stubmaker.pl
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/stubmaker.pl
cp bin/XMLRPCsh.pl blib/script/XMLRPCsh.pl
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/XMLRPCsh.pl
Manifying blib/man1/SOAPsh.pl.1
Manifying blib/man1/stubmaker.pl.1
Manifying blib/man1/XMLRPCsh.pl.1
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Packager.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/UDDI::Lite.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Header.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Client.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/XML::Parser::Lite.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Constants.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Transport::LOOPBACK.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Lite::Packager.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/XMLRPC::Transport::TCP.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/XMLRPC::Transport::POP3.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::SOM.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/XMLRPC::Lite.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Transport.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Schema.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Test.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Apache::SOAP.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Apache::XMLRPC::Lite.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/XMLRPC::Transport::HTTP.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Trace.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Transport::POP3.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Deserializer.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Data.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Server.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/XMLRPC::Test.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Utils.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Serializer.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Fault.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/SOAP::Lite.3pm
  /usr/bin/make  -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/02-payload.t t/05-customxml.t t/010-serializer.t t/096_characters.t t/099_pod_coverage.t t/014_UNIVERSAL_use.t t/03-server.t t/015_UNIVERSAL_can.t t/012-cloneable.t t/08-schema.t t/06-modules.t t/098_pod.t t/01-core.t t/04-attach.t t/07-xmlrpc_payload.t t/013-array-deserialization.t t/097_kwalitee.t t/SOAP/Serializer.t t/SOAP/Data.t t/SOAP/Lite/Packager.t t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchema1999.t t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchemaSOAP1_1.t t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchema2001.t t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchemaSOAP1_2.t t/SOAP/Schema/WSDL.t t/SOAP/Transport/LOCAL.t t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP.t t/SOAP/Transport/IO.t t/SOAP/Transport/MAILTO.t t/SOAP/Transport/POP3.t t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t t/XMLRPC/Lite.t t/XML/Parser/Lite.t
t/01-core....................................ok
        3/42 skipped: various reasons
t/010-serializer.............................ok
t/012-cloneable..............................ok
t/013-array-deserialization..................Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145, <DATA> chunk 1.
t/013-array-deserialization..................ok
t/014_UNIVERSAL_use..........................ok
t/015_UNIVERSAL_can..........................ok
t/02-payload.................................ok
t/03-server..................................Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145.
t/03-server..................................ok
        10/32 skipped:
t/04-attach..................................skipped
        all skipped: Could not find MIME::Parser - is MIME::Tools installed? Aborting.
t/05-customxml...............................Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145, <DATA> line 161.
t/05-customxml...............................ok
t/06-modules.................................ok 1/0Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145.
t/06-modules.................................ok
        6/17 skipped: various reasons
t/07-xmlrpc_payload..........................Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145.
t/07-xmlrpc_payload..........................ok
t/08-schema..................................Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145.
t/08-schema..................................ok
t/096_characters.............................skipped
        all skipped: no reason given
t/097_kwalitee...............................skipped
        all skipped: no reason given
t/098_pod....................................skipped
        all skipped: no reason given
t/099_pod_coverage...........................skipped
        all skipped: no reason given
t/SOAP/Data..................................ok
t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchema1999.......ok
t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchema2001.......ok
t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchemaSOAP1_1....ok
t/SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchemaSOAP1_2....ok
t/SOAP/Lite/Packager.........................ok
t/SOAP/Schema/WSDL...........................ok
t/SOAP/Serializer............................ok
        1/13 skipped: Cannot test without Test::Differences
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP........................ok
        4/36 skipped: various reasons
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI....................Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145.
Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145.

#   Failed test 'return utf8 string'
#   at t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t line 57.
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI....................NOK 1
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI....................NOK 2#   Failed test 'utf8 content: ÃÂberall'
#   at t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t line 59.
#          got: 'ÃÂberall'
#     expected: 'Ãberall'
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 2.
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI....................dubious
        Test returned status 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
DIED. FAILED tests 1-2
        Failed 2/2 tests, 0.00% okay
t/SOAP/Transport/IO..........................ok 1/0Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145.
t/SOAP/Transport/IO..........................ok
        1/8 skipped: cannot test Scalar IO without IO::Scalar
t/SOAP/Transport/LOCAL.......................ok 1/0Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145.
t/SOAP/Transport/LOCAL.......................ok
t/SOAP/Transport/MAILTO......................skipped
        all skipped: Cannot test without Test::MockObject
t/SOAP/Transport/POP3........................ok
t/XML/Parser/Lite............................Subroutine XML::Parser::Lite::_parse_re redefined at /root/.cpan/build/SOAP-Lite-0.715/blib/lib/XML/Parser/Lite.pm line 145.
t/XML/Parser/Lite............................ok
t/XMLRPC/Lite................................ok
Failed Test                 Stat Wstat Total Fail  Failed  List of Failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t    2   512     2    2 100.00%  1-2
6 tests and 25 subtests skipped.
Failed 1/33 test scripts, 96.97% okay. 2/854 subtests failed, 99.77% okay.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Answer (score 6):

For guys with Debian or Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install -y libsoap-lite-perl
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and ended up doing this way. Hope this caters your needs.

1. First download SOAP-Lite Package from http://search.cpan.org/~phred/SOAP-Lite-0.716/
2. Extract the package and remove the folder called "t".
3. `perl Makefile.PL`
4. `make`
5. `make test`
6. `sudo make install`

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
yum install perl-SOAP-Lite
```

or download it from [rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17474994/dir/centos_6/com/perl-SOAP-Lite-0.710.10-2.el6.noarch.rpm.html) and finally

```
rpm -i package.rpm
```

Comment: `No package perl-SOAP-Lite available.`

Comment: OK I downloaded a file from rpm.pbone.net and then how do I install it?

Comment: 'rpm -i perl-SOAP-Lite-0.710.10-2.el6.noarch.rpm
warning: perl-SOAP-Lite-0.710.10-2.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID c105b9de
error: Failed dependencies:
        perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1) is needed by perl-SOAP-Lite-0.710.10-2.el6.noarch
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by perl-SOAP-Lite-0.710.10-2.el6.noarch
        perl(MIME::Lite) is needed by perl-SOAP-Lite-0.710.10-2.el6.noarch
        perl(version) is needed by perl-SOAP-Lite-0.710.10-2.el6.noarch
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by perl-SOAP-Lite-0.710.10-2.el6.noarch`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the test might be broken; I'm seeing

```
t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t .................. 1/? 
#   Failed test 'return utf8 string'
#   at t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t line 57.

#   Failed test 'utf8 content: Ãberall'
#   at t/SOAP/Transport/HTTP/CGI.t line 59.
#          got: 'Ãberall'
#     expected: 'Überall'
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 2.
```

The simplest approach is to extract the module into a temporary folder and remove this test before running:

```
 perl Makefile.PL
 make
 make test
 make install
```

You might, also, want to submit a bug report to the module owner (although this hasn't been touched in over a year)

Comment: Which module and how to remove the test?

Comment: The simplest approach is to force install. `cpan -f SOAP::Lite`.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back: what mob said

Answer (score 0):

you can do a force install with cpan like so:

```
force install SOAP::Lite
```

This worked for me